# How to check if a class obj is null

Tags: c++

I have a hash table (unsorted_map) with a list of vertices. I want to know if a vertex exists in the hash table, however the table itself is private, and the only getter method is a `pointsTo()` function which returns a vertex which this vertex is pointing to.

I want to check if there are no edges pointing to a particular vertex.

```
if(vertices[to]->pointsTo(from) != nullptr)
{
}
```

produces the error `"No operator != matches these operands. Operand types are Edge!=std::nullptr_t"`

De-referencing *(vertices[to]->pointsTo(from)) says "no operator * matches these operands"

Comment: We are not psychic - so tell us the datatypes

Comment: Vertex and Edges are both classes. The operation in the if statement returns an Edge class. (i'm assuming also returns null if it's not in the hash table) @EdHeal

Comment: @userX (please change that) - Why assume? Why not read the the manual page? Probably quicker that typing in this sentence

Comment: This isn't Java. You're dealing with objects, not references.

Comment: @EdHeal It does return null or 0, I've already tried it out

Comment: @EdHeal Emtpy hash index http://ideone.com/WXaG6k

Comment: @penu: It returns 0. But it's not empty. It's an `int` with the value 0. When you call `unordered_map<>::operator[]`, it returns a reference to the object that is there. If there is no object there, it creates one, and default initializes it.

Comment: @penu - Answer by Benjamin would have told you that if you read the manual page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ hash tables and maps don't have a boolean "check if present". If you do

```
m[x]
```

where `x` is not present then a new default-initialized element is created associated to that key.

Quite often however this is not what you want and to check first the C++ way is

```
if (m.find(x) != m.end()) {
    ... element x is present ...
}
```

Another annoyance with standard maps is that given that `[]` is an operation that can mutate the object you cannot use it with const references or when the map values don't have a default constructor. So even in cases you're sure for other reasons that the key will always be present still `m[x]` is a forbidden operation and you need to use `m.at(x)` instead.

Comment: It does (sort of) the `at` method

Comment: @EdHeal: Thanks, added `.at` example.